# unit testing with nunit with integration with jenkins C#

Tags: jenkins, nunit

To preface, I've already installed the Jenkins plugin for NUnit, I'm using the following plugins :

- NUnit v3.12.0
- NUnit3TestAdaptor
- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk
- Microsoft.NETcore.App

All installed via NuGet on Visual Studio 2017.

This is the batch command I'm using to try to run the unit test after being committed to Jenkins.

```
"C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\nunit3-console.exe"
testCSharpe\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\testCSharpe.dll
```

When I build the project, it keeps showing me this error.

[image]

Any idea how to go about this?

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: NUnit3-console does not yet run .NET Core tests.